# Known array / pointer size as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, macros

```
InputManager* input = new InputManager(new int[]{ SDLK_UP, SDLK_DOWN, SDLK_LEFT, SDLK_RIGHT });
```

I wanna pass this array of keys (or a pointer to it) but i need the InputManager's constructor to know its size. Since its known at compile time how would i get it?

Online i found this template

```
template <int N>
InputManager::InputManager(int (&keyArray)[N]) {
    this->maxKeys = N;
    this->keys = keyArray;
}
```

But i get an error that the arguments dont match.

I need any possible solution where i dont need to manually write the length. So macros, templates or anything else is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use so many pointers. It's not healthy and you're likely to either leak memory, or try to free memory that you can't (if you didn't pass a newly-allocated array). Here's a minimal modification of your code:

```
class InputManager {
public:
    template <int N>
    InputManager(int (&keyArray)[N]) 
        : maxKeys(N), keys(std::make_unique<int[]>(N))
    {
        std::copy_n(keyArray, N, keys.get());
    }

private:
    std::size_t maxKeys;
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> keys;
};

int main() {
    int keys[] = { 1, 5, 4, 7, 2 };
    InputManager input {keys};
}
```

This [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/nqaeQL) (GodBolt).

Notes:

- This way, you don't need to write a custom destructor; although you would need to write an assignment operator which copies data; and a copy constructor.
- It's probably better to just use an `std::vector` internally (or `std::array` if you know the input size beforehand), and take any span or range of keys in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap creating of this array into function using variadic template.

If you want only return a pointer to array:

```
template<class ... enums>
int* makeArray (enums ... e) {
    return new int[sizeof...(e)]{e...};
}
```

When you want to know size of returned array you can return `pair`:

```
template<class ... enums>
std::pair< int*, size_t > makeArray2(enums ... e) {
    constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(e);
    return std::make_pair( new int[N]{e...}, N);
}
```